# The usage of first time

Tags: grammar

I am trying to tell something.Let's say I have a friend, he is now in coma and I have never been trying  to figure out what he will want  me to do in the situation I am in but now I am thinking about that.
I formed a sentence like:

> I am thinking what he would have  wanted me to do first time while he is in coma

Is that sentence suitable ?

Comment: "... said no one ever"  :D

Comment: @Andrew I thought that this is a serious platform like stackoverflow , it turns out I was wrong. If  there is anything you want to say , please be clear.

Comment: It's a joke playing off of your user name and a common English expression.  For example, *"'I love going to the dentist!' said no one, ever"*.   I realize this is not really an answer to your question, but I thought it might be fun, and, assuming you didn't already know it, you might enjoy learning this idiom.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for your answer , it is quite explanatory . I am sorry for my previous comment , I thought you were making fun of my sentence :)

Comment: No worries.  I would never make fun of anyone, but I will *have* fun *with* someone. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a serious answer to your question:  I'm not clear that you should include "the first time" in this context, as it feels forced.  It's hard to explain exactly how the phrase is normally used, but most of the time it's for events that are not too unusual or unrealistic.  For example:

> Wow, this is the **first time** I've ever been kidnapped by pirates and forced on a high-seas adventure to find the City of Lost Gold!

is *funny*, because no one would expect to have this specific experience.  On the other hand:

> This is the **first time** I've ever been on a sailboat.

is fine, because it's a reasonable experience.

With your example, "My friend is in a coma and I'm having to make decisions on his behalf," is a little too specific to use "first time".  Instead you might phrase it in a general way:

> This is the **first time** I've had to make tough decisions for someone I care about.

This general context is a more *relatable* life experience.  At some point many of us will have to make these kind of choices, and so we can understand how the situation might feel shocking and difficult.

"The first time" is also used to imply that, because it's a new experience, you feel like you don't know what to do.  Again, while it might make sense in the context of your example, it seems more natural to just talk about your feelings:

> My friend is in a coma and I'm supposed to make decisions on his behalf, and **I honestly don't know what to do.**

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking what he would have wanted me to do first time while he is in coma.

That sentence is a bit awkward, and it seems as if "first time" is qualifying "in coma", as if he has been in coma several times, or you expect him to be so.  I would suggest:

> For the first time I am thinking what he would have wanted me to do, even while he is in coma.

Comment: It seems it will do , I could say that "For the first time I am thinking what he would have wanted me to do and he is in coma now " . But just wanted it to make more fancy . It seems I didn't managed.